# Multiplying binary numbers digit by digit and carry method in Python

Tags: python, performance, number-systems

I have two numbers encoded in a reversed list of digits. First I made multiplication in "Peano" way:

```
#from summa import summa
#from predecessor import predecessor

#def multiply(m, n):
#  def _(b):
#    return [0] if is_zero(b) else summa(m, _(predecessor(b)))
#  return [0] if is_zero(m) or is_zero(n) else summa(m, _(predecessor(n)))
```

but my intention is to find out, if carry method presented below is more efficient.

While the algo itself should work, I need some assistance, if the middle part of it could be optimized. At the moment it looks overly complex, but I haven't find a way to simplify it. Of course it could be an unavoidable effect of the way I have chosen to carry and pass parameters, but if someone could either confirm the case or do some optimization suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
# encode int to binary list
def bn(n):
  return list(reversed(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x == "1" else 0, "{0:b}".format(n)))))

def is_zero(n):
  return not n[1:] and not n[0]

def is_one(n):
  return not n[1:] and n[0]

# multiplication
def multiply2(a, b):
    def _(c, d, f, g, e):
        if not b and not c:
            return g + (e if e[1] else e[:1])
        if c:
            # clumsy part is the formation of A and x
            A = 0 if (0 if (1 if c[0] and d else 0) == (e[1] if e else 0) else 1) == (f[0] if f else 0) else 1
            # x = [0, 0] or [1, 0] or [0, 1] or [1, 1]
            x = [A, 1 if ((e[1] if e else 0) or (f[0] if f else 0)) and c[0] and d or \
                         ((e[1] if e else 0) and (f[0] if f else 0)) and not c[0] and d else 0]
            #print(x, c, d, e, f, g)
            return _(c[1:], d, f[1:], (g + e[:1] if e else g), x)
        return g[:1] + _(a, b.pop(0), g[1:] + e, [], [])
    return [0] if is_zero(a) or is_zero(b) else \
             b if is_one(a) else \
             a if is_one(b) else _(a, b.pop(0), [], [], [])
# test cases
for i in range(101):
  for j in range(101):
    x, y = bn(i*j), multiply2(bn(i), bn(j))
    if x != y:
      print("prod %s * %s = %s:" % (i, j, (i*j)), x, "->", y)
```

Please note the comment: "clumsy part is the formation of A and x" which is due to required optimization.

The last double for loop iterates numbers from 0 to 100 and multiplies them, which is for checking that algo works correctly.

> Note, that I can do only simple comparison, boolean checks and list
>   cut/concat operations on the algo.

### Addition

In the simple sample output:

```
print(multiply2(bn(10), bn(10)), bn(10*10))
```

both lists should be same.

### Also

This algo is based on the schema presented below, althought the one below is using base ten numbers, but carrying logic is same in the right part of the spreadsheet:

[image]

Left part is the common multiplication shema learnt in the elementary schools and one really could to repeated additions as on my commented "Peano" example. But my intuition says `multiply2` method is faster until we really want to go to the Fast Fourier transform algorithms.

Comment: Not a full review, but `bn(n)` could be `bn(n): return list(bin(n))[2:]`.

Comment: Thou not part of the algo, albeit a good tip for improving Python code.

Comment: Can you maybe provide example how this code is supposed to be used? Because at the moment when I run your code, nothing happens

Comment: In the last for loop you can remove if x not y and then you see print to work. At the moment print triggers only if algo doesnt return correct answer. Enough or still need to change the  example?

Comment: @MarkokraM What version of python are you using?

Comment: 3.6.1 (default, Jun 21 2017, 18:48:35)  [GCC 4.9.2] but intended to use it on 2.7 also.

Comment: @Coal_ I think `bn` should rather be: `list(reversed(list(map(int, bin(n)[2:]))))` because the list needs to be in reversed order for the algo to work correctly. Or is there a easier way to reverse the list for this? Oh and items in list needs to be integers, not strings as on your simpler version.

Comment: `return list(bin(n))[:1:-1]` Shoudl work, but don't let me spoil my answer too much ;)

Comment: @Ludisposed changed function according to your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Note that you may not incorporate answers into your question, This is called answer invalidation (or comment invalidation in this particular case) and is frowned upon on CR. Best would be to change back your code to the original

Comment: So you mean map int bin case should be returned to original one that is on comments now? No problem I can do that if thats what you mean. Hopefully it is recognized that bn function is not part of the algo but just for simpler access to binary encoded numerals in list format.

Answer (score 1):

## Python style

*Style is important! Will you be able to read this code after a few months? I have a really hard time understanding this at first sight.*

- Use a `if __name__ == '__main__'`
- Use built-ins like this `bn(n):   return list(map(int, bin(n)[:1:-1]))]` as suggested by @Coal_ with some changes to reverse the bin representation and change it a an integer
- Use indentation of `4` spaces, this will make your code alot more readable. Currently you have mixed `4` indent with `2` indent, my eyes don't like this :)
- Use more descriptive names, `_(c, d, e, f, g)` what do they mean? It is not clear for a Code reviewer.
- Don't try to shorten lines as much as possible. For instance,

> ```
> return [0] if is_zero(a) or is_zero(b) else \
>         b if is_one(a) else \
>         a if is_one(b) else _(a, b.pop(0), [], [], [])
> ```

This is short I agree, but not really nice to read or discriptive what it does at first sight.

```
if is_zero(a) or is_zero(b):
    return [0]    
elif is_one(a):
    return b
elif is_one(b):
    return a    
else:
    ....
```

Reads alot better in my opinion.

I would suggest to read up on [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which has alot of nice pointers for Python style.

## Algo

This should be possible without recursion, when I choose a big value you will get an error:

```
print(multiply2(bn(100000000000), bn(100000000000)), bn(100000000000*100000000000))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

You could avoid this by increasing the recursion depth but this is more of a hack then a solution.

*How about a `stack` based approach to avoid the recursion?*

---

## Alternative approach

*Using a stack based approach*

```
def bn(n):
    return list(map(int, bin(n)[:1:-1]))

def is_zero(n):
    return not n[1:] and not n[0]

def add_lists(first, second):
    n = max(len(first), len(second))
    first += [0] * (n - len(first))
    second += [0] * (n - len(second))
    return [first[i] + second[i] for i in range(n)]

def carry_over(first_num, second_num):
    stack, overflow = [], 0
    for i in range(len(second_num)):
        if second_num[i] == 1:
            stack = add_lists(stack, [0] * i + first_num)

    for i in range(len(stack)):
        stack[i] += overflow
        overflow = stack[i] // 2
        stack[i] %= 2

    while overflow > 0:
        stack.append(overflow % 2)
        overflow //= 2

    return stack

def multiply2(first_num, second_num):    
    if is_zero(first_num) or is_zero(second_num):
        return [0]  
    else:
        return carry_over(first_num, second_num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test cases
    for i in range(101):
        for j in range(101):
            print(f"{multiply2(bn(i), bn(j))}, {bn(i*j)}")
```

Comment: Im actually using Python to transfer algo to different platform where Im limited to use very limited set of language constructors. Im not totally sure but stack based isnt possible there, only recursion. But I really need to consider this if good solution comes up. And you are right, I had to increase recursion limit to 10000 to get bigger numbers working. I fully understand naming conventions. But I also noticed that by simplest possible names some patterns of the code can be recognized visually from the structure itself which is kind of cool. So style indeed is important in many ways.

Comment: @MarkokraMc What do you mean by "limited set of language constructors"? And why should a stack based solution not be possible?

Comment: It means the DSL I'm using has short-circuit operators and list processing capabilities and that loops needs to be created by anonymous recursion, no side effects are allowed for example. This possibly limits using stack based approach?

Comment: @MarkokraM Added alternative, and I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: Using ´len´, ´max´, ´for´ list comprehension, ´mod´/´idiv´ functions, ´multiplication´, ´minus´, ´plus´, they all add a lot more language constructors than I was hoping. Could ´mod´/´idiv´ be replaced by booleans checks because in binary only 0 and 1 are expected operands? Anyway, I think I need to digest more with this and play around to see, how could I apply...

Comment: Also is_zero `1 not in n` requires searching until the end of the list? We could time these two versions...

Comment: So in stack approach two lists are unified to contain same amount of items first, zeros for "null" items so to say. Also items are added so that they can be 0, 1 or 2. On the second loop carrying is handled by overflow variable if item value is 2. And final loop appends the rest of the overflow until 0 is reached. Is this the correct interpretation of the algo?

Comment: Yes, Pretty much

Comment: Interesting is the fact that you add the first number with leading zeros as many as there are digits until every 1 (`[0] * i + first_num`) in the second number. How did you conclude that is the way to do it?

Comment: In `add_lists` we could minimize the length retrieval and get rid of the `max` because all info is already available on the indices, something like: https://gist.github.com/markomanninen/f57e44c0666bf0cfab66a736aade8135 Also it looks like the second list is always bigger so it will be as it is...

Comment: On the seventh revision of the `carry_over` function I noticed that this stack approach quite much  implements the left side of the picture I added to my question: https://gist.github.com/markomanninen/f57e44c0666bf0cfab66a736aade8135 I'd like to see the right side implementation as I have proposed on my original code and explanation, wheather in stack or recursive manner.